# Lists and Values of the list in C#

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, for-loop, sharepoint-deployment

I am from PHP, and I don't think I am understanding how to walk through data structures properly. The documentation for [SPFieldCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472869.aspx) is pretty clear what kind of arguments it takes, so I wrote a class that does:

```
namespace SPAPI.Lists.Add
{
    class AddParams
    {
        public SPFieldType type { get; set; }
        public bool required { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From there I created a list that does:

```
public Create(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, Dictionary<string, List<AddParams>> columns, string name, string description, SPListTemplateType type)
{
    SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    if (siteCollection != null)
    {
        SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
        web.Lists.Add(name, description, type);
        web.Update();

        // Add the new list and the new content.
        SPList spList = web.Lists[name];
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<AddParams>> col in columns){
            spList.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value[0], col.Value[1]);
        }

        // More Code ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't like `col.Value[0]`, `col.Value[1]` because one is not a `SPFieldType` and the other isn't a `boolean` by strict definition. I think I have the right Idea, but I am looking for guidance on how to make this work.

Because C# has type hinting I assumed that it would use the `AddParams` class to see the types.

The idea is to pass in a series of params and create a new list based on those params.

This is more of a C# question and data structure iteration question then a SP development question.

Comment: Have you tried casting col.Value[0] and col.Value[1] to their respective types?

Comment: @Rubixus Cast what...those would both be AddParams, just the first one and the second one.

Comment: @Don Maybe I didn't understand your question. To me, it seemed your problem was that col.Value[0] should be added to Fields as a SPFieldType, and col.Value[1] should be boolean. But after seeing Igor's answer, I see what you were after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
spList.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value[0], col.Value[1]);
```

to

```
spList.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value[0].type, col.Value[0].required);
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `col.Value[0]` and `col.Value[1]` are of `AddParams` type. This will probably compile:

```
spList.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value[0].type, col.Value[0].required);
```

but you likely need another `foreach` inside your `foreach`:

```
foreach(AddParams item in col.Value)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have list of `AddParams`?  Are you expecting more than 1 `FieldType` for the same field?

I think you should implement it this way:

```
public Create(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, Dictionary<string, AddParams> columns, string name, string description, SPListTemplateType type)
{
    SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    if (siteCollection != null)
    {
        SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
        web.Lists.Add(name, description, type);
        web.Update();

        // Add the new list and the new content.
        SPList spList = web.Lists[name];
        foreach(string key in columns.Keys){
            spList.Fields.Add(key, columns[key].type, columns[key].required);
        }

        // More Code ...
    }
}
```